# get the count from query

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

```
Select Count(*),
(select Name from Tours Where Tours.ID = TourBooking.TourID) as Name,
(select Url from Tours Where Tours.ID = TourBooking.TourID) as Url,
(select Top 1 Name from TourImages Where TourImages.TourID = TourBooking.TourID Order By ID Asc) as ImageName,
(Select Duration +' '+ CASE WHEN  DurationType = 'd' THEN 'Day(s)' WHEN  DurationType = 'h' THEN 'Hour(s)' END from Tours Where Tours.ID = TourBooking.TourID)as Duration,
(select replace(replace('<a> Adult(s) - <c> Children','<a>', sum(case when [Type] = 1 then 1 else 0 end)                      ),
'<c>', sum(case when [Type] = 2 then 1 else 0 end)) from TourPerson Where TourPerson.BookingId = TourBooking.ID) as TotalPassengers,
StartDate,CreatedDate as BookingDate,ID as BookingID,[Status],ServicePrice
from TourBooking
```

How to get the count from this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get the count from this query

I think you're *trying* to do that with your first `COUNT(*)` statement. Instead you could try nesting your whole query and get the count that way.

```
SELECT COUNT(innerTable.*), innerTable.* FROM (
SELECT
(select Name from Tours Where Tours.ID = TourBooking.TourID) as Name,
(select Url from Tours Where Tours.ID = TourBooking.TourID) as Url,
(select Top 1 Name from TourImages Where TourImages.TourID = TourBooking.TourID Order By ID Asc) as ImageName,
(Select Duration +' '+ CASE WHEN  DurationType = 'd' THEN 'Day(s)' WHEN  DurationType = 'h' THEN 'Hour(s)' END from Tours Where Tours.ID = TourBooking.TourID)as Duration,
(select replace(replace('<a> Adult(s) - <c> Children','<a>', sum(case when [Type] = 1 then 1 else 0 end)                      ),
'<c>', sum(case when [Type] = 2 then 1 else 0 end)) from TourPerson Where TourPerson.BookingId = TourBooking.ID) as TotalPassengers,
StartDate,CreatedDate as BookingDate,ID as BookingID,[Status],ServicePrice
from TourBooking ) as innerTable
```

Comment: Column 'innerTable.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Mike Then it looks like your inner query isn't working. Probably has to do with the `sum` functions you're using. Take those out and see if it works.